# How to submit a web page with different IP?

Tags: linux, ip, submit, netfilter

i dont want to do something illegal with it(e.g. vote continuously, in fact, somebody is doing it), but i only feel curious about it. For i have learned TCP/IP, and i found there are many software such like "IP changer",using which you can submit a website with different IP. WOW it is really magic! so i analysed some possible mechanism about it. But every possible way was denied by me.

1. i thought that they might connect and disconnect the internet continuously. because each time they connect the Internet, the ISP will dispatch a new IP address, and the hacker can make use of the new IP to submit the website, and disconnected after submitting successfully, and then connect for the next time...But it is impossible to some extent, for if do like this, every submitting will last a long time, and it doesn't work in some areas.
2. Modify TCP/IP data packets.For some time i did think it might be all right. but then i denied it. Assuming that i would submit a website, and i changed the IP address of the data packet which i will submit to the web site. it seems that everything is OK, but the web server will send message to the fake IP, so i wont get any information from the website. but in some circumstances where we only needn't reply it should work. Right? ***netfilter*** and ***iptables*** in linux may realize it, but i am not sure because i dont know the tools very well.
3. Using proxy server. i also think it is impossible to some extent.is there any method to get lots of free proxy servers? and most free proxy servers is very unstabitily, for there is a possible circumstance that you cannot use the proxy server in one day.Of course, paid proxy server may be permanent. but with these money you can do something better.

IMO the three methods all have disadvantages. and the realization may be none of them. Can anybody tell me the real mechanism of the technique?

Comment: +1 and added to fav, very interesting question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lots of proxy servers. That will do the trick and since they can be harvested quite easily that's not very hard. Proxy's can be installed on hacked websites for example.

The added question:

> Using proxy server. i also think it is impossible to some extent.is there any method to get lots of free proxy servers?

By simply hacking lots of webservers, totally automated, this is possible. For example searching for bad Joomla installs could allow you to install software at each webserver. Also normal computers can be used off course. Like a botnet.

> and most free proxy servers is very unstabitily, for there is a possible circumstance that you cannot use the proxy server in one day. Of course, paid proxy server may be permanent. but with these money you can do something better.

Stability is off course important but in this case not really actually. You just send out lots and lots and lots of requests. Don't care which one succeeds and which one doesn't. It doesn't matter for your target.

Comment: thx, i have considered it before, i forgot to write it here...now i have added it in the question above.i also think it is impossible to some extent.is there any method to get lots of free proxy servers? and most free proxy servers is very unstabitily, for there is a possible circumstance that you cannot use the proxy server in one day.Of course, paid proxy server may be permanent. but with these money you can do something better.

Comment: Edited the answer, stability and things are not relevant for your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. ISP reconnect

This will not work for some (most?) ISPs which will reassign the same IP on a reconnect (as my provider does). Even if it works, you are likely to get the same IP address after some reconnects.

#### 2. IP spoofing

That's the term describing your second method. You change the `src`-address of the outgoing IP packet. There are two problems with that:

- Most ISP's routers don't allow it. They detect that the `src` address can't come from inside their network, so they simply drop it.
- If you have a machine that is allowed to do this (maybe a dedicated server), you can only fake exactly *one* IP frame. This allows you to, e.g. spoof a DNS request but as you said, you will never get the response. Especially you cannot establish a connection within a stateful protocol like TCP, because this requires a bidirectional handshake. So you can't, e.g., fake a HTTP request using this (even if you don't need the answer)

#### Proxying

This is the only method that works. You have several options here:

- Use open proxy servers (can be found using a search engine, although some will identify themselves as proxies and provide the original IP in the `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header, which makes them basically useless for this use case)
- Use hacked servers/desktop machines as proxies (maybe from a botnet)
- Use free networks like JAP or TOR (the latter of which is probably your best bet, because you can change the exit nodes using some trickery)

Comment: proxying is a good idea, i have also considered it before, but i only wonder one question: is there enough proxies i can use? you also offered some ways to get proxy servers. Yes, it is also the only method that i think is possible. i didnt know something like JAP or TOR very well. i will search for the mechanism of them. thx.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do something illegal, you might as well go all the way in. There ARE people who run "botnets" which are basically just armies of a few hundred to a few thousand indfected computers (that's what most viruses do). The people who run these armies, actually can charge people a certain amount of money for their "slaves" to visit a website for you (and rate/vote whatever) so you get a few hundred or a few thousand more ratings...

I can't exactly tell where or how much these services cost, since I haven't done it myself, but I know for sure that people over at "H@ckf0rums.net" will do it for you.

Comment: maybe it's a choice for those who want to get more ratings. but comparing with that, i am more interested at how to change ip continuously.Anyhow, you let me know a method to rate a voting in an extremely short time, which i didnt know before. thx all the same

Comment: @MarkZar - If you want to change your ip continuously, the only way I can see this for free, is Tor. You just click "change exit relay" every time you want a new IP. If you want a faster solution, then go with a dynamic VPN. You can sometimes find one that lets you get a new IP whenever you want.